# How to create an Angular Element with Angular Material?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am creating an Angular Element in which I am using Angular Material design. The Material contents are not getting rendered in the browser, but it's showing up on the DOM.

My element template looks like this:

```
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Settings</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Help</button>
</mat-menu>

<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>Click Me!
</button>
```

[Final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE3nT.jpg)

Comment: I have added a "Final output" image to the question. Have a look, please!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

For mat-menu it's not rendered inside HTML until it's not visible.

You could check this [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d7e6ok) click on last button.

Comment: Thanks! However, my issue is Material design isn't loading in my Angular ELEMENT.

Comment: @AnikSau please recheck Demo I'll add your html code with mat-icon and it's renderd inside button in DOM